# Concerning the Attribute Flat

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, attributes

Suppose we have a function `f` with the Attribute Flat. From my understanding, the following command should return all possible ways of rewriting `f[a,b,c]` as a function of two arguments at all levels:

```
Attributes[f] = {Flat};
f[a,b,c] /. f[x_,y_] /; Print[{x,y}] :> Null;
```

This command evaluates to

```
{f[a],f[b,c]}
{f[a,b],f[c]}    
{a,f[b,c]}    
{f[a,b],c}    
{f[a],f[b]}    
{a,b}    
{f[b],f[c]}    
{b,c}
```

My question: why are the level 2 cases `{a,f[b]}`, `{f[a],b}`, `{b,f[c]}`, and `{f[c],b}` not included? Similarly, when the following command is executed,

```
Attributes[f] = {Flat};
f[a,b,c,d] /. f[x_,y_] /; Print[{x,y}] :> Null;
```

why does it return two instances of `{f[a,b],f[c,d]}`?

I am running Mathematica 11.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Can you use ReplaceList and see what happens?  I’m worried the pattern matcher might be behaving a bit differently because of the Condition you threw in there...

Comment: @QuantumDot ReplaceList returns only rewritings at level 1, i.e. the first four cases of the output of the first command in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Please pardon this non-answer but it doesn't fit nicely in a comment.

In version 10.1 under Windows I get different results:

```
Attributes[f] = {Flat};

f[a, b, c] /. f[x_, y_] /; Print[{x, y}] :> Null;
```

> {f[a],f[b,c]}
>
> {f[a,b],f[c]}
>
> {f[a],f[b]}
>
> {f[b],f[c]}

```
f[a, b, c, d] /. f[x_, y_] /; Print[{x, y}] :> Null;
```

> {f[a],f[b,c,d]}
>
> {f[a,b],f[c,d]}
>
> {f[a,b,c],f[d]}
>
> {f[a],f[b,c]}
>
> {f[a,b],f[c]}
>
> {f[b],f[c,d]}
>
> {f[b,c],f[d]}
>
> {f[a],f[b]}
>
> {f[b],f[c]}
>
> {f[c],f[d]}